# PyPDF to read each PDF in a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

I have the code below which is working. But it only reads one file at a time, which I have to insert in the code. How could I make this code read every PDF in a directory? PDF by PDF.

```
import PyPDF2
import textract
import re

filename = 'file.pdf' 
pdfFileObj = open(filename,'rb')               
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)   
num_pages = pdfReader.numPages  

count = 0
extractedtext = ""

while count < num_pages:                       
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(count)
    count +=1
    wortlaut += pageObj.extractText()

print(extractedtext)    

keyword = re.findall(r'(\d{7})(\-)(\d{2})',extractedtext)
if keyword:
print(keyword)
```

Comment: Which part are you struggling with, specifically? Do you know how to use loops?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to get a list of PDF files in a directory.
You can also accept a command-line argument for the directory within which to operate.
Call this program with: `python3 this_script.py directory_to_read`

```
import PyPDF2
import glob 
import os 
import re
import sys

dir_to_read = sys.argv[1] # accept a command-line argument with the dir to read
pdf_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_to_read,'*.pdf'))

count = 0
extractedtext = ""
for pdf_file in pdf_files:
    print(pdf_file)
    pdfFileObj = open(pdf_file,'rb')               
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)   
    num_pages = pdfReader.numPages  

    print(num_pages)

    while count < num_pages:                       
        pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(count)
        count +=1
        extractedtext += pageObj.extractText()

    print(extractedtext)    

    keyword = re.findall(r'(\d{7})(\-)(\d{2})',extractedtext)
    if keyword:
        print(keyword)
```